# Get RAW SQL Query from Eloquent with Eager Loading

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$books = Book::with(array('score' => function($query) use ($id)
            {
               $query->where('media_type_id','=',$id)->orderBy('sorting_score','ASC');
            }))->get();
```

I have one table with books and one table with media_score - I have a belongTo relationship.

When I do toSQL(); it returns me select * from books only rather than an eager loading equivalent.

I need the eager loading equivalent because I wish to use a caching system (without the remember function) so I would like to use the raw query as a key.

do dumping the query log is not an option because it happens AFTER the query got ran.

Comment: The query builder has a function `getEagerLoads()` you could potentially use here.

Comment: when i do getEagerLoads instead of get() - I get a blank

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha as mentioned the query is to make a hash key so dumping via query log is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
  Book::with(array('score' => function($query) use ($id)
            {
               $query->where('media_type_id','=',$id)->orderBy('sorting_score','ASC');
            }))->get();

$query_dump = DB::getQueryLog();
```

and print `$query_dump`

Answer (score 1):

Try this [plugin](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) by barryvdh. It would really help you debug you laravel app. It include several collectors

> 1. **QueryCollector**: Show all queries, including binding + timing.
> 2. **RouteCollector**: Show information about the current Route.
> 3. **ViewCollector**: Show the currently loaded views. (Optionally: display the shared data)
> 4. **EventsCollector**: Show all events.
>
> etc.

Happy coding;